# How to demonstrate numpy gradient usage with a given 2-d function?

Tags: python, numpy, math

I'm quite confused by numpy gradient usage on N-D array. I write some code snippets to understand its usage on 1-D array as the following:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# 1-d
t = np.linspace(0, 0.04, 101)
w = 2*np.pi*50
y = np.sin(w*t)

dy = w * np.cos(w*t)
dy_numeric = np.gradient(y, 0.0004, edge_order=1)

plt.plot(t, y, label='f')
plt.plot(t, dy, label='df')
plt.plot(t, dy_numeric, label='df_num')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

The example above shows how it works and its internal relationships.But I can't do the same with a given 2-d function as the following:

```py
x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 201)
y = np.linspace(-10, 10, 201)
f = x ** 2  + y ** 2
df_dx = 2 * x
df_dy = 2 * y

# the exact gradient expression of this 2-d function is [2*x, 2*y]
# but how can I use np.gradient to compute its numeric values?
# df_vals = np.gradient(?,?)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your 2D snippet is that `f` is not 2D at all. If you try `print(f.shape)` you will get `(201,)`.

You can instead try the following to get numeric values of the gradient along X and Y directions.

```py
# 2-d
x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 201)
y = np.linspace(-10, 10, 201)

def func(x, y):
    return x**2 + y**2
f = func(x[:, None], y[None, :])

df_dx = 2 * x
df_dy = 2 * y
df_dx_numeric, df_dy_numeric = np.gradient(f, 0.0004, edge_order=1)
```

As you can test, `f.shape` is now `(201,201)` as expected.

Comment: Wonderful! Exactly what I want!  Thank you.